# Linux kernel module to list children of a given pid

Tags: c, linux, process, kernel, pid

I am trying to implement a module which takes pid as input parameter and lists all children pids when the module is loaded, i.e. insmod is called. However, I do not know how to achieve this goal. I tried something by looking some tutorials.

So far, I am able to get input, load the module and find task by its pid. What I am not able to do is: I cannot list children pids.

Here is my init function:

```
int pid_init(void){

    if(pid == -1){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "No input entered!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    struct pid *pid_struct = find_get_pid(pid);
    struct task_struct *parent = pid_task(pid_struct, PIDTYPE_PID);

    if(parent == NULL){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "No process found!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    struct task_struct *task;
    struct list_head *list;

    printk(KERN_INFO "%d\n", parent->pid);

    list_for_each(list, &parent->children) {
        task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
        printk(KERN_INFO "%d\n", task->pid);
    }


   return 0;
}
```

I tried in following pids: (output of `pstree -p`)

```
├─udisksd(783)─┬─{udisksd}(792)
               ├─{udisksd}(795)
               ├─{udisksd}(898)
               └─{udisksd}(920)
```

When I call: `sudo insmod module.ko pid=783`

Output is: `783` which is printed by me, so it means `list_for_each` is not called.

However, when I call `sleep 100 &` three times and execute `sudo insmod module.ko` with `pid=<bash>`

Then I can list pids of `sleep 100 &` calls. 
Finally, I am using `Ubuntu` in case you need to know.

Comment: There is a [complete example here](https://github.com/posborne/linux-programming-interface-exercises/blob/master/12-system-and-process-information/pstree.c) that does what you have described.  If you want _complete_ answers about some of the things you are asking, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Indeed, I wonder why I can list pids of sleep calls but cannot list for udisksd(783) @ryyker

Comment: You will likely get fuller, more complete, easier to find answers about all things Linux [in the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).  For this specific question (in your comment) [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347085/udisks-smart-apm-stopped-working).